# QueryBuilder with foreach and multiple params

Tags: symfony, updates, query-builder

I want to have a generic update method, which receive a json with {field1:value1,.. field4:value4} and update all of them . Where field are the field name from the table in the DB.
It could be only one field to update, but also severals.

In my symfony controller :

```
 /**
     * @Route("/update", name="template_update", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function update(Request $request, TemplateRepository $templateRepository): Response
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $fields = $data["data"];
        $qb = $templateRepository->createQueryBuilder('t');

        foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
            dump($field);
            dump($value);
            $q = $qb->update(Template::class,'t')
            ->set("t." . $field . "", '?1')
            ->where('t.id = ?2')
            ->setParameter(1, $value)
            ->setParameter(2, $data["id"])
            ->getQuery();
            dump($q);
            $p = $q->execute();
        }
        return new JsonResponse(["response" => $p]);
    }
```

On the first loop it's ok : [image]

But second loop, the previous param remain and is overwrited by this last query :
[image]

What I am doing wrong ? And is there a better way to avoid multiple query and do it in one unique query ?

Comment: I think you need a new query builder for each update query.

Comment: That's it I don't see it

Comment: Thanks @IwanWijaya !

Comment: I mean you need to run createQueryBuilder() for each loop. it may work, but writing code like this is not really secure and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Ok answer was I declare only once my querybuilder outside of the foreach.
Put it inside the foreach and there isn't more error.

I also figure out how to do it in one query :

```
    $qb = $templateRepository->createQueryBuilder('t');
    $qb->update(Template::class, 't');
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
        $qb->set("t." . $field . "", '?' . $count . '')
            ->setParameter($count, $value);
        $count++;
    };
    $q = $qb->where('t.id = ?' . $count . '')
        ->setParameter($count, $data["id"])
        ->getQuery();
    $p = $q->execute();
```

Comment: Just be aware that since $field is coming from an external source, you are vulnerable to sql injections.  Unlike data fields no processing is done for column names.  At the very least you need to validate $field.

Comment: That's a good point, you mean just a strip_tags and things like that on $field /$value ?

Comment: I would just have an array of valid field names and check that $field is one of them.

Comment: I wonder if you could just fetch the Template from database and call appropriate setters and then flush to db and only got one query and it's going to be escaped properly by default ... obviously only works if you got a normal mapping between properties and column names

Comment: or even more, use a deserializer to fill the object with data ... ;o)